# Wso2 esb soap with encoding file base64 to mailto transport

Tags: soap, email-attachments, wso2-esb

I have a proxy service who receive an soap message with an encoding base64 file and I try to send an email messsage with an attachment file.
Here is my soap incomming message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
  <RetrieveMultipleResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices">
     <RetrieveMultipleResult EntityName="annotation" MoreRecords="0" PagingCookie="">
        <BusinessEntities xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/WebServices">
           <BusinessEntity xsi:type="q1:annotation" xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices">
              <q1:documentbody>V2ViIFNlcnZpY2UgTWVzc2FnZSBBdHRhY2hlZA0K</q1:documentbody>
           </BusinessEntity>
        </BusinessEntities>
     </RetrieveMultipleResult>
  </RetrieveMultipleResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here is my sequence :

```
<property name="transport.mail.Format"
                     value="Attachment"
                     scope="axis2"
                     type="STRING"/>
           <property name="AttachmentFile"
                     value="facture.pdf"
                     scope="axis2"
                     type="STRING"/>
           <property name="messageType"
                     value="application/octet-stream"
                     scope="axis2"
                     type="STRING"/>
           <property name="ContentType"
                     value="application/octet-stream"
                     scope="axis2"
                     type="STRING"/>
           <property name="Subject"
                     value="File Received"
                     scope="transport"
                     type="STRING"/>
           <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
           <property name="STATUS"
                     value="EXIT_REQUEST"
                     scope="default"
                     type="STRING"/>
           <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
              <format>
                 <attachment>
                    <contentID>$1</contentID>
                 </attachment>
              </format>
              <args>
                 <arg xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices"
                      evaluator="xml"
                      expression="//q1:documentbody"/>
              </args>
           </payloadFactory>
           <send>
              <endpoint>
                 <address uri="mailto:exp@domaine.com"/>
              </endpoint>
           </send>
```

The email that I receive give me the attach file with the encode text inside.

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,
Nicolas